# Does Intellij / Datagrip support stored functions?

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, oracle-sqldeveloper, stored-functions, datagrip

Does Intellij / Datagrip support stored functions?

Using the same connection details I can see the function object in SQLDeveloper but not in Intellij IDEA. I'm not sure if this is due to a lack of support in Intellij IDEA or some other reason.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type = 'FUNCTION'
  AND object_name = 'DUMMYFUNCTIONNAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

Database view window contains all your data sources and their schemas with tables, functions, and views, etc. divided into folders which can be collapsed and expanded:

[image]

Make sure you have selected the schema you want to inspect in Database view:

[image]

and run [**Synchronize**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html#synch) action from database view for this data source for IDE to fill up the schema with database objects.

See more procedures you can do in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html).